# How do I return a value from a C# function using jint?

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

I'm currently using Jint (https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) to process JavaScript.

I would like to be able to use a custom function in JavaScript that will execute a function created in C# and then return a value to the JavaScript.

For example if the JavaScript was:

```
var x = MultiplyByTwo(100);
```

And in my C# I had:

```
private static int MultiplyByTwo(int obj)
{
    return obj * 2;
}
```

Then the above would give the variable x the value of 200.

According to the Documentation there is the following option:

```
var engine = new Engine()
.SetValue("log", new Action<object>(Console.WriteLine));

engine.Execute(@"
    function hello() { 
        log('Hello World');
    };
 
    hello();
");
```

I can replace the "Console.Writeline" with a function name but it will only accept a void function.
In other words, this can call a C# function from JS but not return a value.

Does an option like what I am looking for exist in Jint?

Comment: `Action` only accepts void functions, the see [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0) if you want a return value. However, the linked page has a complete section about "Accessing .NET assemblies and classes", have you tried that?

Comment: You would have to be looking for maybe an overload of `SetValue` or maybe a different method that takes a `Func<>` or similar. In fact, I'd just boldly try to pass a Func and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fully functional example. Casting `Console.WriteLine` is required since there are multiple overloads and we need to tell the compiler which one to use:

```cs
using System;
using Jint;

var engine = new Engine()
    .SetValue("multiplyByTwo", MultiplyByTwo)
    .SetValue("log", (Action<string>)Console.WriteLine)
    ;
    
engine.Execute(@"
    var x = multiplyByTwo(3);
    log(x);
");

static int MultiplyByTwo(int obj)
{
    return obj * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly reference a class, which can involve setting properties, and methods can return values. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myobj = new MyClass();
        var engine = new Engine()
            .SetValue("log", new Action<object>(Console.WriteLine))
            .SetValue("myobj", myobj);

        engine.Execute(@"
        function hello() { 
            myobj.One = 'asdf';
            var x = myobj.TwoTimes(4);
            log(x); // logs 8
        };
    
        hello();
    ");
        Console.WriteLine($"{myobj.One}, {myobj.Two}");
        // output => "asdf 8"
    }

}

public class MyClass
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public int Two { get; set; }
    public int TwoTimes(int value)
    {
        Two = 2 * value;
        return Two;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some comments, use

```cs
SetValue("multiplyByTwo", new Func<int>(MultiplyByTwo))
```

Comment: Or even just `.SetValue("MultiplyByTwo", MultiplyByTwo);` - since (like in most other cases), the C# compiler will infer the type of the method and add the creation of the required delegate implicitly.